# Right way to implement a collectionView where each cell has a remove button

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

To make a collectionView where each cell has a delete button, I can think of two ways:

1. Create a custom cell that has the delete button.

   **Cons:**  We have to create a custom cell from an existing cell just to add a delete button, and if we want to reuse the collectionView to display different types of cells, we have to make a subclass for each cell type.
2. Add the delete button to each cell in the collectionView's cellForItemAt method.

   **Cons:**  The datasource method should be providing the data, not modifying the UI of cell. On top of that, since cells will be reused, we need to use view tag to check if the button has been added or not, which is not recommended (for example: some third party library might use the same view tag to do other things).

Which approach is better? Or are there better ways to achieve the same goal?

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: A swipe action is not an option? By the way a custom cell is not a Con.

Comment: @vadian In my case, I need a custom deletion button, and I consider a custom cell as a Con because the original cell's UI design is complex.

Comment: You can add the delete button in the original cell UI, make it hidden by default. Then show it when you need it.

Comment: @RickMo Good Idea, I have thought the same thing.